# string <br/> to HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my aSP.NET MVC model, I build a string, the result of this string is :

```
"MyName1 <br/> MyName2 <br/> MyName3"
```

I'd like see in my HTML page the result like this :
MyNAme1
MyName2
MyName3

and not the stirng

```
"MyName1 <br/> MyName2 <br/> MyName3"
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is outputting the string without HTML encoding. If you are using the Razor view engine:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MyString)
```

And if you're using the WebForms view engine:

```
<%= Model.MyString %>
```